# Within a React app, what is the correct way to query an API that requires an Oauth token

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, axios, ebay-api

Ebay is closing its Finding API and my React application needs to move to the Browse API https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/buy/browse/overview.html and I need to use Oauth.  My app does not require a user to authenticate with Ebay, it just shows the ebay auctions that are relevant to the page they are looking at.  Within my Ebay developer account I have an application that provides an `App ID (Client ID)` and `Cert ID (Client Secret)`, however I just cannot figure out how to manage the refresh token request and the application token request so that I can actually send a request to the Browse API.

*My question is: within a React application, what is the correct way to use oauth refresh and authorisation tokens, and use them to successfully make a request to an Oauth protected endpoint (in this case Ebay’s)?*

I have an Ebay React component (shown at the bottom of this question) and I’ve ‘borrowed’ much of this from [How to get access_token using refresh token from Ebay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66744901/how-to-get-access-token-using-refresh-token-from-ebay)

However in that question `const refreshToken = 'xxxxxxxx';` is mentioned and I can’t figure out how to get one.  Ebay has documentation on using a refresh token https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/oauth-refresh-token-request.html which says:

```
Configuring the request payload
Format the payload of your POST request with the following values:
- Set grant_type to refresh_token.
- Set refresh_token to the refresh token value returned from the authorization code grant request.
```

So this looks as though I get the refresh token in a response to an authorisation request which seems to be documented at https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/oauth-client-credentials-grant.html for applications such as mine (not users).  Following this example I can make a cURL request

```
curl -X POST 'https://api.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic U3DFSDF888888D00000000000000=' \   //not the real details
  -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&scope=https%3A%2F% 2Fapi.ebay.com%2Foauth%2Fapi_scope' 
  -u 'StuartBrr-PRD-cd00000-0000000:PRD-0000-00000-0000-000-000'  //not the real details
```

Which returns
`{"access_token":"v^1.1#i^1#p^1#I^3#r^0#f^0#t^H4sI……","expires_in":7200,"token_type":"Application Access Token"}%`
But there is no mention of a refresh token.  So I suppose I could run a request against the API using that token, but it would only work until the refresh token expired.

If I run

```
curl 'https://api.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token' 
-d 'grant_type=refresh_token&scope=https%3A%2F% 2Fapi.ebay.com%2Foauth%2Fapi_scope' 
-u 'StuartBrr-PRD-cd00000-0000000:PRD-0000-00000-0000-000-000'
```

I get a response `{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"the provided authorization refresh token is invalid or was issued to another client"}%`

If I run my React application including the below component I can see a preflight request which is successful, and another request which reports a CORS error.
[image]

The request with the CORS error is passing the below headers in the payload
[image]

So I can’t even get the response which only gives me the Application Access Token, let alone make a subsequent call to the Ebay Browse API

Any guidance very much appreciated!

Below if the React component I have that attempts to get the token and I would like to make the API request

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import queryString from 'query-string';

class Ebay extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
  
      this.state = {
        loading: true,
        results: true,
        error: "",
        data: [],
      };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
       //Prod
       const appID = 'StuartBrr-PRD-cd00000-0000000;  // these are obviously not the real details
       const certID = 'PRD-0000-00000-0000-000-000;
       const URL = 'https://api.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token';
       //sandbox
       // const appID = 'StuartBr-STr-SBX-b0000000-00000000';
       // const certID = 'SBX-0000000-00000-000-0000-0000;
       // const URL = 'https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token';
       const token = Buffer.from(`${appID}:${certID}`);
       const scopes = [
         'https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope'
   ]
       const { data } = axios.post(URL, {
       'headers': {
         'Authorization': `Basic ${token.toString('base64')}`,
         'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
       },
     })
   console.log("HERE IS AXOIS DATA "+ JSON.stringify(data));
    }
  
    render() {
       console.log("IN EBAY COMPONENT");
//   Render results in a table
      
    }
  }
  export default Ebay;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup `auth_accepted_url` in developer account first,

then call
`https://auth.ebay.com/oauth2/authorize` with all parameters

in this way, after authentication, in `auth_accepted_url`
you will receive, together with auth_token, the refresh_token with its lifespan.

eBay documentation is not very clear so it requires you to read it twice.